# Copy items with similar filenames from CSV content

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I am attempting to create a simple script that can read a CSV file, and find files (.jpgs) with names that contain the CSV contents and then copy those files to a new location.

The CSV contents will be in the following format, 'files' is the header:

```
Files
------
B000000001
B000000002
```

The file names will be in the following format:

```
B000000001.PT01.jpg
B000000002.PT03.jpg
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
$ASINs = Import-Csv "C:\share_test.csv"
foreach($ASIN in $ASINs){
GCI -Path "C:\test1" | Where-Object{$_.Name -like $ASIN} | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\test2"
}
```

I am not getting errors, but it is not copying the files that match. I seem to always have trouble with Copy-Item when it gets this specific, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok thank you all for the advice. This is what I have now:

```
$ASINs = Import-Csv "C:\share_test.csv"
foreach($ASIN in $ASINs){
GCI -Path "C:\test1" -Filter '*$ASIN*' | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\test2"
}
```

Still no dice! What am I doing wrong? I tried the `-Filter` with and without quotations.

Thanks again!

Comment: You're not getting any errors because you're not comparing objects properly and your pipeline is empty.  `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test1' -Filter *$ASIN*`, no need for `Where-Object` to validate a filename; it just slows things down.

Answer (score 1):

The `-like` operator allows wildcards, but without wildcards, it works just like `-eq`,  i.e. you are looking for e.g. a file name that is exactly `B000000001` instead of `B000000001.PT01.jpg`.

You can solve this by adding wildcards as required:

```
 Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*$ASIN*"}
```

It's faster and recommended to filter "left" though:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test1" -Filter "*$ASIN*"
```

In this case, there is no need for the `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this a quick try and there were a couple changes I had to make.
Firstly I used the -match operator and secondly I included the property Files when using the operator

```
Where-Object{$_.Name -match $ASIN.files}
```

I tried testing what @vrdse mentioned with by comparing a string and $ASIN using the following

```
"B0003" -like "*$Asin*"
```

But that also didn't return anything until I changed it to

```
"B0003" -like "*$($Asin.files)*"
```